# Consistent size for symbols in ggsave and gganimate's 'animate'

Tags: r, png, gif, resolution, gganimate

My end goal is to create two outputs:

1) A static image showing all of my data, saved as a `png`
2) An animation of my data, saved as a `gif`.

I'm using `ggplot2` and `gganimate` and I'm puzzled as to why the symbol size is not consistent between the two save methods.

I've tried adjusting the `dpi` and saving as `jpg` instead of `png`, but no luck. **Can anyone help me figure out how to make the width, height, and symbol size in both output objects consistent?**

Here's a reproducible example showing both outputs. You can see that the black points are smaller in the `gif`.

### Make the `png`

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)

locs <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                   y = c(1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 6),
                   LDT = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

g <- ggplot(locs, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "pink"))
g
ggsave("test.png", g, width = 2, height = 2, dpi = 100)
```

[image]

### Make the `gif`

```
anim <- g + transition_time(LDT)
animate(anim, duration = 1, fps = 20, width = 200, height = 200)
anim_save("test.gif")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`animate()` by default uses `png()` to generate frames.

In your `ggsave` call you specified a plot resolution of 100 dpi.

To get the same result using `png` you'll have to set `res = 100` (see `test_png_device.png`).

Accordingly to have a consistent symbol size using `animate` you'll have to pass the resolution to `png` as an optional argument to `animate` as follows:

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)
library(gifski)

locs <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                   y = c(1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 6),
                   LDT = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

g <- ggplot(locs, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "pink"))

ggsave("test.png", g, width = 2, height = 2, dpi = 100)

png(filename = "test_png_device.png", width = 200, height = 200, units = "px", res = 100)
g
dev.off()

anim <- g + transition_time(LDT)
myAnimation <- animate(anim, duration = 1, fps = 20, width = 200, height = 200, renderer = gifski_renderer(), res = 100)
anim_save("test.gif", animation = myAnimation)
```

---

[image: ggsave][image: Result]

---

**Addition**: Not sure if you are interested in this, however, I like using library([plotly](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/animations/)) for animations since it adds an animation slider by default.

Here is the `ggplotly`-way for your example:

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

locs <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                   y = c(1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 6),
                   LDT = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

g <- ggplot(locs, aes(x, y)) + theme_void() + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "pink")) +
  geom_point(aes(frame = LDT))

p <- ggplotly(g) %>% 
  animation_opts(500, easing = "linear", redraw = FALSE)

saveWidget(p, file = "myAnimation.html", selfcontained = TRUE)
browseURL("myAnimation.html")
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67087965/r-shiny-exported-png-resolution-is-different-when-running-app-local-vs-deploye/67090951#67090951) a related post can be found.

Comment: I knew it would be simple but I just couldn't get it! Thanks for taking the time to help me out. Also great tip with the `plotly` library. I like to embed animations in powerpoint presentations so the .mp4 format works better for me. Just need to figure out the right codec so PowerPoint can actually play the darn things!

Comment: Glad I could help!  Microsoft [recommends](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-and-audio-file-formats-supported-in-powerpoint-d8b12450-26db-4c7b-a5c1-593d3418fb59) .mp4 files encoded with H.264 video. Good luck with it. Cheers

Comment: Done! Sorry, I thought awarding the bounty did that automatically - thanks for the push!