# R Shiny: Exported PNG Resolution is Different when Running App Local vs. Deployed

Tags: r, image, deployment, shiny, png

I want to create a PNG image with a manually specified resolution in a deployed Shiny app. This PNG image should be saved in my Dropbox. For some reason, the deployed version of my Shiny app does not take the `res` argument within the `png` function into account.

Consider the following example:

```
##### Load R packages #####


library("rdrop2")
library("shiny")
library("shinythemes")


##### Define UI #####


ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                
                path_now <<- tempdir(),

                mainPanel(tags$h1("My Input"),
                      
                          textInput("some_text", "Insert Some Text", "Some Text"),
                          textOutput("some_text_txtout"),
            
                          actionButton("do", "Run"),
                ))


##### Define server function #####


server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$do, {

    fun_some_text <- reactive({
      input$some_text
    })

    some_text <<- fun_some_text()

    outfile <- tempfile(fileext = "my_identifier.png")

    png(outfile, 
        width = 1500,
        height = 1000,
        res = 10)

    par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
    par(bg = "green")

    N <- 5000
    x <- runif(N)
    y <- runif(N)

    plot(x, y, type = "l", xlim = c(0.1, 0.9), ylim = c(0.1, 0.9))

    points(0.5, 0.5, col = "green", cex = 1700, pch = 16)

    text(0.5, 0.575, some_text, cex = 50)

    dev.off()

    token <- readRDS("droptoken.rds")

    file_path <- file.path(path_now, list.files(path_now, pattern = "my_identifier")[1])
    file_path <- gsub("\\\\", "/", file_path)

    drop_upload(file_path,
                path = "responses",
                dtoken = token)
  })
}


##### Create Shiny object #####


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I run this app locally, the following PNG image is created:

[image]

However, when I deploy exactly the same app to shinyapps.io and run it online, the following PNG image is created:

[image]

As you can see, the resolution of the second image is much larger, i.e. the `res = 10` argument that I have specified within the `png` function was not taken into account in the deployed version of the app.

I am new to Shiny, so I assume that I'm missing something very basic. However, after 2 days of research I still didn't find a solution.

**Question: How could I specify the PNG resolution in a deployed Shiny app?**

Comment: Unfortunately your example isn't reproducible. However, I guess your problem is OS and not `shiny` related. System independent image rendering is a [difficult topic](https://www.jumpingrivers.com/blog/r-graphics-cairo-png-pdf-saving/). You might want to check [library(ragg)](https://github.com/r-lib/ragg).

Comment: Are you developing on a windows machine? I guess you are using Windows GDI. You can reproduce the `shinyapps.io` behaviour by setting `type = "cairo"` in the `png`-call.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Please see my comments below your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following to check if the ragg output remains identical on your system and shinyapps.io:

```
##### Load R packages #####
library("shiny")
library("shinythemes")
library("ragg")

createPNG <- function(text_input, res, type){
  outfile <- tempfile(fileext = paste0("_", gsub(" ","_", gsub(":",".", Sys.time())), "_", type, ".png"))
  
  if(type == "ragg"){
    agg_png(outfile, width = 1500, height = 1000, res = res)
  } else {
    png(outfile, 
        width = 1500,
        height = 1000,
        res = res, type = type)
  }
  
  par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  par(bg = "green")
  
  N <- 5000
  x <- runif(N)
  y <- runif(N)
  
  plot(x, y, type = "l", xlim = c(0.1, 0.9), ylim = c(0.1, 0.9))
  points(0.5, 0.5, col = "green", cex = 1700, pch = 16)
  text(0.5, 0.575, text_input, cex = 50)
  invisible(dev.off())
  outfile
}

##### Define UI #####
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                path_now,
                mainPanel(tags$h1("My Input"),
                          textInput("some_text", "Insert Some Text", "Some Text"),
                          verbatimTextOutput("pngPaths"),
                          numericInput("resolution", "resolution", value = 10, min = 1, max = 20),
                          actionButton("do", "Run")
                ))


##### Define server function #####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  pngPaths <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    cairoPath <- createPNG(input$some_text, input$resolution, "cairo")
    windowsPath <- createPNG(input$some_text, input$resolution, "windows")
    raggPath <- createPNG(input$some_text, input$resolution, "ragg")
    
    pngPaths(list(cairoPath, windowsPath, raggPath))
    
    if(Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Windows"){
      shell.exec(dirname(cairoPath))
    }
  })
  
  output$pngPaths <- renderPrint(req(pngPaths()))
}


##### Create Shiny object #####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858687/consistent-size-for-symbols-in-ggsave-and-gganimates-animate/58950189#58950189) a related post can be found.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, this clarifies a lot! Indeed, when I run my code with type = "cairo" in the png call (as suggested in your comment above), I end up with exactly the same plots. When I run the entire code of your answer locally, the ragg and cairo pngs look similar (I think the font type is not identical), and the windows png looks very different. When I try to run the code on the server, the log of shinyapps.io returns the error `Warning: Error in match.arg: 'arg' should be in '“cairo”, “cairo-png”, “Xlib”, “quartz”'`...

Comment: ...Would it be possible to create graphics in Windows-style on the shinyapps.io server? This is very important to me, because my code will create numerous different graphics and I have already specified the parameters of those graphics based on the Windows-style. Thanks again!

Comment: The error on shinyapps.io is occuring due to the fact that it is hosted on Linux. Accordingly `type = "windows"` is not available. You can comment out that function call to avoid the error.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! If I comment out `type = "windows"` the script works fine. However, the perfect output would be a graphic in Windows-style. Do you know how I could create a graphic in Windows-style using the shinyapps.io server?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. As mentioned before I'd suggest using `ragg` and modifying the plotting code to be future proof. I'll try to look at this again tomorrow (currently only on mobile). Have you thought about using the windows-png as a template - only adding the text when hosted on Linux? E.g. see `image_annotate()` from `library(magick)`.

Comment: Just to end this cleanly: I havn't found any hints on how to replicate the behaviour of the Windows GDI in this scenario. Using base R the output remains OS specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to me! I continued to work on the problem and have just managed to convert my Windows-based code to the cairo library. Thanks again for your support, it has helped me a lot to find a final solution!

Comment: So in the end you changed the plotting code to have it look similar to the windows output? Or what is your solution?

Comment: Exactly. I'm now using the cairo library on Windows as well and have modified all plotting parameters accordingly.