# Why does the chart_Series chart look blurry in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod

Why does the chart look blurry in  shiny and how can I fix it?

```
library(quantmod) 
library(shiny)

symb <- as.xts(getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign = FALSE))
symb <- tail(symb,50)

#  good look chart example
chart_Series(symb)
```

[image]

Here is an example application

```
#  bad look chart example
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("Chart")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Chart <- renderPlot({
       chart_Series(symb)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

##### upd

I don't understand why is that?
[image]

```
other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.7.4     quantmod_0.4.22 TTR_0.24.3      xts_0.13.1      zoo_1.8-12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting a higher resolution in `renderPlot` and / or change the plot `width`/`height` in `plotOutput`:

```
library(quantmod) 
library(shiny)

symb <- as.xts(getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign = FALSE))
symb <- tail(symb,50)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("Chart", width = "658px", height = "496px")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Chart <- renderPlot({
    chart_Series(symb)
  },
  res = 100)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, but the graph still doesn't look the same as in the first case.
Or is that a chart_Series problem?

Comment: If you want it to look exactly the same you'll need to find the default resolution (+ width/height) of the initial plot.

Comment: Can I figure it out automatically, or do it manually?

Comment: Furthermore, please check my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67087965/r-shiny-exported-png-resolution-is-different-when-running-app-local-vs-deploye/67090951#67090951) and library([ragg](https://ragg.r-lib.org/)).

Comment: can you suggest what should I do with the package to get a good picture?

Comment: I just updated the code with the defaults I found in my RStudio installation (guess this is where your "good" plot comes from).

Comment: unfortunately it only got worse 
http://prntscr.com/ZdwuY0kKNDX5